# Getting 404 Not Found in $batch of Odata

Tags: odata, linq-to-dataset, odata4j

I am new to Odata.I have send multiple Post Request to Same Url.Then Getting exeption

`"**http://localhost:25907/odata/$batch**"`

Not Found Please any one help me how to handle this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first implement batch in server side.

Here is how to do it with Web API:Introducing batch support in Web API and Web API OData
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/01/introducing-batch-support-in-web-api-and-web-api-odata.aspx

Comment: Please provide more details in your answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to first implement batch in server side.

Here is how to do it with Web API:[Introducing batch support in Web API and Web API OData](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/01/introducing-batch-support-in-web-api-and-web-api-odata.aspx)